# Gaussian fit returning negative sigma

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

One of my algorithms performs automatic peak detection based on a Gaussian function, and then later determines the the edges based either on a multiplier (user setting) of the sigma or the 'full width at half maximum'. In the scenario where a user specified that he/she wants the peak limited at 2 Sigma, the algorithm takes -/+ 2*sigma from the peak center (mu). However, I noticed that the sigma returned by `curve_fit` can be negative, which is something that has been noticed before as can be seen [here](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/6014). However, as I determine the border by doing -/+ this can lead to the algorithm 'failing' (due to a - - scenario) as can be seen in the following code.

MVCE

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import bisect
import numpy as np

X = [16.4697402328,16.4701402404,16.4705402481,16.4709402557,16.4713402633,16.4717402709,16.4721402785,16.4725402862,16.4729402938,16.4733403014,16.473740309,16.4741403166,16.4745403243,16.4749403319,16.4753403395,16.4757403471,16.4761403547,16.4765403623,16.47694037,16.4773403776,16.4777403852,16.4781403928,16.4785404004,16.4789404081,16.4793404157,16.4797404233,16.4801404309,16.4805404385,16.4809404462,16.4813404538,16.4817404614,16.482140469,16.4825404766,16.4829404843,16.4833404919,16.4837404995,16.4841405071,16.4845405147,16.4849405224,16.48534053,16.4857405376,16.4861405452,16.4865405528,16.4869405604,16.4873405681,16.4877405757,16.4881405833,16.4885405909,16.4889405985,16.4893406062,16.4897406138,16.4901406214,16.490540629,16.4909406366,16.4913406443,16.4917406519,16.4921406595,16.4925406671,16.4929406747,16.4933406824,16.49374069,16.4941406976,16.4945407052,16.4949407128,16.4953407205,16.4957407281,16.4961407357,16.4965407433,16.4969407509,16.4973407585,16.4977407662,16.4981407738,16.4985407814,16.498940789,16.4993407966,16.4997408043,16.5001408119,16.5005408195,16.5009408271,16.5013408347,16.5017408424,16.50214085,16.5025408576,16.5029408652,16.5033408728,16.5037408805,16.5041408881,16.5045408957,16.5049409033,16.5053409109,16.5057409186,16.5061409262,16.5065409338,16.5069409414,16.507340949,16.5077409566,16.5081409643,16.5085409719,16.5089409795,16.5093409871,16.5097409947,16.5101410024,16.51054101,16.5109410176,16.5113410252,16.5117410328,16.5121410405,16.5125410481,16.5129410557,16.5133410633,16.5137410709,16.5141410786,16.5145410862,16.5149410938,16.5153411014,16.515741109,16.5161411166,16.5165411243,16.5169411319,16.5173411395,16.5177411471,16.5181411547,16.5185411624,16.51894117,16.5193411776,16.5197411852,16.5201411928,16.5205412005,16.5209412081,16.5213412157,16.5217412233,16.5221412309,16.5225412386,16.5229412462,16.5233412538,16.5237412614,16.524141269,16.5245412767,16.5249412843,16.5253412919,16.5257412995,16.5261413071,16.5265413147,16.5269413224,16.52734133,16.5277413376,16.5281413452,16.5285413528,16.5289413605,16.5293413681,16.5297413757,16.5301413833,16.5305413909,16.5309413986,16.5313414062,16.5317414138,16.5321414214,16.532541429,16.5329414367,16.5333414443,16.5337414519,16.5341414595,16.5345414671,16.5349414748,16.5353414824,16.53574149,16.5361414976,16.5365415052,16.5369415128,16.5373415205,16.5377415281,16.5381415357,16.5385415433,16.5389415509,16.5393415586,16.5397415662,16.5401415738,16.5405415814,16.540941589,16.5413415967,16.5417416043,16.5421416119,16.5425416195,16.5429416271,16.5433416348,16.5437416424,16.54414165,16.5445416576,16.5449416652,16.5453416729,16.5457416805,16.5461416881,16.5465416957,16.5469417033,16.5473417109,16.5477417186,16.5481417262,16.5485417338,16.5489417414,16.549341749,16.5497417567,16.5501417643,16.5505417719,16.5509417795,16.5513417871,16.5517417948,16.5521418024,16.55254181,16.5529418176,16.5533418252,16.5537418329,16.5541418405,16.5545418481,16.5549418557,16.5553418633,16.5557418709,16.5561418786,16.5565418862,16.5569418938,16.5573419014,16.557741909,16.5581419167,16.5585419243,16.5589419319,16.5593419395,16.5597419471,16.5601419548,16.5605419624,16.56094197,16.5613419776,16.5617419852,16.5621419929,16.5625420005,16.5629420081,16.5633420157,16.5637420233,16.564142031]
Y = [11579127.8554,11671781.7263,11764419.0191,11857026.0444,11949589.1124,12042094.5338,12134528.6188,12226877.6781,12319128.0219,12411265.9609,12503277.8053,12595149.8657,12686868.4525,12778419.8762,12869790.334,12960965.209,13051929.5278,13142668.3154,13233166.5969,13323409.3973,13413381.7417,13503068.6552,13592455.1627,13681526.2894,13770267.0602,13858662.5004,13946697.6348,14034357.4886,14121627.0868,14208491.4544,14294935.6166,14380944.5984,14466503.4248,14551597.1208,14636210.7116,14720329.3102,14803938.4081,14887023.5981,14969570.4732,15051564.6263,15132991.6503,15213837.1383,15294086.683,15373725.8775,15452740.3147,15531115.5875,15608837.2888,15685891.0116,15762262.3488,15837936.8934,15912900.2382,15987137.9762,16060635.7004,16133379.0036,16205353.4789,16276544.72,16346938.7731,16416522.8674,16485284.4226,16553210.8587,16620289.5956,16686508.0531,16751853.6511,16816313.8096,16879875.9485,16942527.4876,17004255.8468,17065048.446,17124892.7052,17183776.0442,17241685.8829,17298609.6412,17354534.739,17409448.5962,17463338.6327,17516192.2683,17567996.9463,17618741.7702,17668418.588,17717019.5043,17764536.6238,17810962.0514,17856287.8916,17900506.2493,17943609.2292,17985588.936,18026437.4744,18066146.9493,18104709.4653,18142117.1271,18178362.0396,18213436.3074,18247332.0352,18280041.3279,18311556.2901,18341869.0265,18370971.642,18398856.332,18425517.6188,18450952.493,18475158.064,18498131.4412,18519869.7341,18540370.0523,18559629.505,18577645.202,18594414.2525,18609933.7661,18624200.8523,18637212.6205,18648966.1802,18659458.6408,18668687.1119,18676648.7029,18683340.5233,18688759.6825,18692903.29,18695768.4553,18697352.5327,18697655.9558,18696681.2608,18694431.0245,18690907.8241,18686114.2363,18680052.838,18672726.2063,18664136.918,18654287.5501,18643180.6795,18630818.883,18617204.7377,18602340.8204,18586229.7081,18568873.9777,18550276.2061,18530438.9703,18509364.8471,18487056.4135,18463516.2464,18438747.4526,18412756.9228,18385553.1936,18357144.808,18327540.3094,18296748.2409,18264777.1456,18231635.5669,18197332.0479,18161875.1318,18125273.3619,18087535.2812,18048669.4331,18008684.3606,17967588.6071,17925390.7158,17882099.2297,17837722.6922,17792269.6464,17745748.6355,17698168.2027,17649537.512,17599868.3744,17549173.3069,17497464.8262,17444755.4492,17391057.6927,17336384.0736,17280747.1087,17224159.3148,17166633.2088,17108181.3075,17048816.1277,16988550.1864,16927396.0002,16865366.0862,16802472.961,16738729.1416,16674147.1447,16608739.4873,16542518.6861,16475497.2591,16407688.2541,16339106.0951,16269765.4262,16199680.8916,16128867.1358,16057338.8029,15985110.5372,15912196.9829,15838612.7844,15764372.5859,15689491.0316,15613982.7659,15537862.4329,15461144.6771,15383844.1425,15305975.4735,15227553.3143,15148592.3093,15069107.1026,14989112.3386,14908622.6595,14827652.5673,14746216.3337,14664328.209,14582002.4435,14499253.2874,14416094.9911,14332541.8049,14248607.9791,14164307.764,14079655.4098,13994665.1668,13909351.2855,13823728.016,13737809.6086,13651610.3137,13565144.3816,13478426.0625,13391469.6068,13304289.2646,13216899.2865,13129313.8865,13041546.3657,12953609.0623,12865514.2686,12777274.277,12688901.3798,12600407.8693,12511806.0378,12423108.1777,12334326.5812,12245473.5407,12156561.3486,12067602.297,11978608.6785,11889592.7852]

def gaussFunction(x, *p):
    """Define and return a Gaussian function.

    This function returns the value of a Gaussian function, using the
    A, mu and sigma value that is provided as *p.

    Keyword arguments:
    x -- number
    p -- A, mu and sigma numbers
    """
    A, mu, sigma = p
    return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))

newGaussX = np.linspace(10, 25, 2500*(X[-1]-X[0]))
p0 = [np.max(Y), X[np.argmax(Y)],0.1]

coeff, var_matrix = curve_fit(gaussFunction, X, Y, p0)
newGaussY = gaussFunction(newGaussX, *coeff)

print "Sigma is "+str(coeff[2])

# Original
low = bisect.bisect_left(newGaussX,coeff[1]-2*coeff[2])
high = bisect.bisect_right(newGaussX,coeff[1]+2*coeff[2])
print newGaussX[low], newGaussX[high]

# Absolute
low = bisect.bisect_left(newGaussX,coeff[1]-2*abs(coeff[2]))
high = bisect.bisect_right(newGaussX,coeff[1]+2*abs(coeff[2]))
print newGaussX[low], newGaussX[high]
```

Bottom-line, is taking the `abs()` of the sigma 'correct' or should this problem be solved in a different way?

Comment: Well, as sigma only enters the argument of the exponential as squared value, I don't see a problem with using the absolute value. On the other hand, if you use sigma also to normalise your normal distribution, i.e. multiplying it with `1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)`, you probably get around the 'problem' altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are fitting a function `gaussFunction` that does not care whether sigma is positive or negative. So whether you get a positive or negative result is mostly a matter of luck, and taking the absolute value of the returned `sigma` is fine. Also consider other possibilities:

1. (Suggested by Thomas Kühn): modify the model function so that it cares about the sign of sigma. Bringing it closer to the normalized Gaussian form would be enough: the formula  `A/np.sqrt(sigma)*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))` would ensure that you get positive sigma only. A possible, mild downside is that the function takes a bit longer to compute.
2. Use the variance, sigma_squared, as a parameter:

   ```
   A, mu, sigma_squared = p
   return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma_squared))
   ```

This is probably easiest in terms of keeping the model equation simple. You will need to square your initial guess for that parameter, and take square root when you need sigma itself.

---

Aside: you hardcoded `0.1` as a guess for standard deviation. This probably should be based on data, like this:

```
peak = X[Y > np.exp(-0.5)*Y.max()]
guess_sigma = 0.5*(peak.max() - peak.min())
```

The idea is that within one standard deviation of the mean, the values of the Gaussian are greater than `np.exp(-0.5)` times the maximum value. So the first line locates this "peak" and the second takes half of its width as the guess for sigma.

For the above to work, X and Y should be already converted to NumPy arrays, e.g., `X = np.array([16.4697402328,16.4701402404,....`. This is a good idea in general: otherwise, you are making each NumPy method that receives X or Y make this conversion again.

Comment: I have to admit that hard coding a guess at 0.1 is something that snuck in and I never stopped to think about, as such I love the idea of basing it on peak max/min parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You might find lmfit (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful for this. It includes a Gaussian Model for curve-fitting that does normalize the Gaussian and also restricts `sigma` to be positive using a parameter transformation that is more gentle than `abs(sigma)`.   Your example would look like this

```
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel
xdat = np.array(X)
ydat = np.array(Y)

model = GaussianModel()
params = model.guess(ydat, x=xdat)
result = model.fit(ydat, params, x=xdat)

print(result.fit_report())
```

which will print a report with best-fit values and estimated uncertainties for all the parameters, and include FWHM.

```
[[Model]]
    Model(gaussian)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 31
    # data points      = 237
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 95927408861.607
    reduced chi-square = 409946191.716
    Akaike info crit   = 4703.055
    Bayesian info crit = 4713.459
[[Variables]]
    sigma:       0.04880178 +/- 1.57e-05 (0.03%) (init= 0.0314006)
    center:      16.5174203 +/- 8.01e-06 (0.00%) (init= 16.51754)
    amplitude:   2.2859e+06 +/- 586.4103 (0.03%) (init= 670578.1)
    fwhm:        0.11491942 +/- 3.51e-05 (0.03%)  == '2.3548200*sigma'
    height:      1.8687e+07 +/- 910.0152 (0.00%)  == '0.3989423*amplitude/max(1.e-15, sigma)'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(sigma, amplitude)          =  0.949
```

The values for `center +/- 2*sigma` would be found with

```
xlo = result.params['center'].value - 2 * result.params['sigma'].value
xhi = result.params['center'].value + 2 * result.params['sigma'].value
```

You can use the `result` to evaluate the model with fitted parameters and different X values:

```
newGaussX = np.linspace(10, 25, 2500*(X[-1]-X[0]))
newGaussY = result.eval(x=newGaussX)
```

I would also recommend using `numpy.where` to find the location of `center+/-2*sigma` instead of bisect:

```
low  = np.where(newGaussX > xlo)[0][0]     # replace bisect_left
high = np.where(newGaussX <= xhi)[0][-1] + 1 # replace bisect_right
```

Comment: I had never heard of `numpy.where` before, I will have a look at it. I am curious as to why it would be faster than a `bisect` tho?

Comment: @BasJansen `numpy.where` will use numpy ndarrays, and work in C, whereas `bisect` works on heterogeneous lists using a `while` loop in Python.  It may not be noticeable for smallish arrays, but will be for large arrays.  Then again, I got the usage wrong(now fixed!), so maybe `bisect` is more "obvious".   Anyway, that was a small part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I came up with a trivial but effective solution, which is basically to use the variance in the gaussian function definition instead of the standard deviation, since the variance is always positive. Then, you get the std_dev by square rooting the variance, obtaining a positive value i.e., the std_dev will always be positive. So, problem solved easily ;)

I mean, create the function this way:

```
def gaussian(x, Heigh, Mean, Variance):
   return Heigh * np.exp(- (x-Mean)**2 / (2 * Variance))
```

Instead of:

```
def gaussian(x, Heigh, Mean, Std_dev):
   return Heigh * np.exp(- (x-Mean)**2 / (2 * Std_dev**2))
```

And then do the fit as usual.