# Fitting a cumulative gaussian to data

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit a cumulative Gaussian distribution to my data, but I get a strange result with negative mu... :

libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
```

First I am importing the data from an Excel

```
data = pd.read_excel ('....xlsx',sheet_name='test', na_filter=True)
```

the data look like:

[image]

then creating a data frame:

```
data_sort = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y'])
```

and fit the pdf:

```
mu,sigma = curve_fit(norm.cdf, data_sort['x'], data_sort['y'], p0=[0,1])[0]
```

and I get back mu= -0.512, sigma=0.106, which is just totally wrong...

Comment: It would probably be helpful to tag the library you are using as that will increases the chance you get an answer, and also include that in your question: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: I have included all the libraries

Comment: More importantly tag the library (I have tagged for you), so someone familiar with those libraries can help. Here is a related question that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47773178/gaussian-fit-returning-negative-sigma

Comment: The range of any CDF is [0, 1]. The y axis of your graph goes up to 100, so there is no way for `curve_fit` to create a good fit of `norm.cdf` to your data.  Check the scaling of your data--is it percentages rather than probabilities?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser ... this is true of course! thank you